# Strapi - Cannot find module '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk'

Tags: javascript, mapbox, strapi

I would like use this package https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js from a Strapi service, so I installed it like that:

```
npm install @mapbox/mapbox-sdk
```

And I added this code at the top of `api/address/services/address.js` file:

```
const mbxClient = require('@mapbox/mapbox-sdk');
const geocodingService = require("@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding");
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Cannot find module '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk'

However the package has been installed because I see it in the `node_modules` folder

What is the problem and how to solve it please?

Comment: Finally, I used Axios instead of this package.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by installing this additional package

```
npm i --save-dev @types/mapbox__mapbox-sdk
```